# I have money in a bank in South Korea and need to get it to the United States

Tags: united-states, money-transfer, international-transfer, south-korea

I live in the United States. How do I transfer the money here without going to Korea to pick it up?

I tried opening an account with World Bank but the money doesn't get to me even though the bank in Korea sends it to them.  Help Please!

Comment: Can't you just call your bank and do a wire transfer? Or do it online?

Comment: You opened an account with World Bank???  Really???

Comment: Fundamentally to "transfer money" around the world you use a wire transfer.

Comment: @TTT South Korea is famous for its capital controls.

Answer (score 2):

1. phone the bank
2. say you want to do a "wire transfer"

It's that easy.  You'll have to give them the "account number" of your new bank in the USA.

Very likely, you will have to fax them a form, depending on the bank.  It could be that the Korean bank has the ability to "send wires" on their online site (many/most banks outside of the USA have this), in which case your solution is easy.

All exactly as said in the first comment by @TTT.

---

Second approach, simply use a service which exists for exactly this purpose. So, ofx.com or transferwise.com or other competitors. Telephone them, explain your situation, and they will tell if you can do it.

Comment: Have you ever tried to initiate a wire transfer over the phone? I couldn't even get my old bank to temporarily raise my debit card limit over the phone.

Comment: hi Eric - right, I didn't mean you could do it "over the phone", but they'll get you started. Very likely OP will send documents. I've done this 100 times (ie, with banks that don't simply have an online system for wires).

Comment: transferwise.com is typically the cheapest option amongst the solutions listed in this answer.

Comment: I find OFX is cheaper than Transferwise every time, that's just us @FranckDernoncourt - you may be tricked by the "fees" idiocy.  the overall cost of rate + fees (when I have used it) is cheaper at ofx